# How can I update Database after changes in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables with foreign key, first one is:

tblFile : FileID, FileName...

And the second one is:

tblChild (in Datagridview) : ChildID, ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID.

When the Save button is clicked (in the Form), how can I update all the rows in second table if rows (Add or Edit or Delete)? (Form ex: https://i.postimg.cc/jq7Ks3CW/1.jpg)

I tried this:

```
    public void dgvChildUpdate(DataGridView dgv, TextBox txtID)
{
    string ChID;
    DataTable dtNew = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
    DataTable dtDel = dtNew.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);

    if (dtDel != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtDel.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblFileChild WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", ClsDB.con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", dtDel.Rows[i]["ChildID"].ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    dtDel = null;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblChild WHERE fkFileID = @FileID", ClsDB.con))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < dt.Rows.Count; t++)
            {
                ChID = dt.Rows[t]["ChildID"].ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ChID == dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmdChild = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblChild SET ChildName = @ChildName, ChildBirthDate = @ChildBirthDate WHERE ChildID = @ChildID", ClsDB.con))
                        {
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildID", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                            cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                            cmdChild.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rowCh in dgv.Rows)
        {
            ChID = rowCh.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            if (ChID == string.Empty)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdChild = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblChild (ChildName, ChildBirthDate, fkFileID) VALUES (@ChildName, @ChildBirthDate, (SELECT FileID FROM tblFile WHERE FileID = @FileID))", ClsDB.con))
                {
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildName", rowCh.Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildBirthDate", rowCh.Cells[3].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmdChild.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", txtID.Text.Trim());
                    cmdChild.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can show you how to make this very easy, but you might have to come to terms with throwing away most of what has been written..

Comment: Ok, I will try.. Go on..

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: I'll type it up in a bit; got a conf call atm.. SMor means "don't use AddWithValue with SQLServer", but it's not a solution to your current problem, more a general advice on good SQLS querying practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a couple of tables in a scratch db to represent your setup. I'm not a fan of prefixing tables with tbl etc but i've left it in to demo how we don't have to have it in the c# even if it's in the DB (I would recommend to not prefix anything in a db)

Here's my version of your DB:

[image]

Make a new project, add a DataSet type of file and open it. Right click the surface, add a tableadapter

[image]

configure the connection string etc, choose Add from statements

[image]

Put a query that pulls by primary key

[image]

Add "ByFileId" to the names of the queries

[image]

Finish, and rename the generated datatable to remove the "tbl"

[image]

Repeat the process for the other table. You should see the relation appear too

[image]

That's your data access part sorted. You can look at the huge amount of well parameterized SQL code VS has written for you in the DataSetX.Designer.cs if you want to. It has not only parameterized the queries, preventing SQL injection hacking, but it's also added extra code to retrieve values (like the IDs) that are calculated by the db, and also bits to detect if someone else has changed a record while you've had it, so you can manage the potential conflict:

[image]

Open a new form in a designer mode, and show the data sources window (View menu, Other windows - hope you're using .net framework):

[image]

There are two Child nodes in the data sources because one is top level and one is related to the File; we'll use the File one because it'll demo loading and saving related data

Drag the following nodes onto the form:

[image]

I'm not trying to win any beauty contests here; just demoing a concept. Tarting it up can come later

That's it; everything needed to load update and save data has been done. You're right; i didn't write a single line of code

Let's put some dummy data into the db:

[image]
[image]

And, before we load the app, I'll just tweak a property on the tableadapter that will make it easier to load lots of data (because the only queries in the dataset at the moment can only load one record at once). Turn off ClearBeforeFill in both tableAdapters (in the tray under the form)

[image]

Run the app. I loaded all the data available in my db by entering 1 in the box, clicking Fill, changing to 2, Fill, then in the child box 1, fill, 2, fill, 3, fill - remember this is just a demo; all this can be done programmatically, and with different queries that select by name etc (tableadapters can have multiple queries)

[image]

You can click the nav at the top to switch the file between 1 and 2 and note the related records in the grid updates automatically:

[image]

you can edit anything you see and hit save

[image]

And it's in the DB and done..

[image]

If you'd added decords or deleted records, those changes would be saved too, by `Update()` - it doesn't just call UPDATE queries, despite being called Update()

It's not magic, by the way; you can find all the code that did it in the .Designer files and the form codebehind.. it's just that it's *all code that VS can do a better job of writing than we can* so leave VS to do it, and just use the code it wrote for you

---

So how do we make these things useful? Querying by PK is all well and good but you don't ask a user to type PKs.. You can add more queries to your tableadapters that do other stuff:

[image]

[image]

Having added these queries to your adapters you could ask your user for a filename, then run a code like:

```
fileTableAdapter.FillByName(someDataset.File, filenametextbox.Text);
foreach(var f in someDataset.File){
  childTableAdapter.FillByFileId(someDataset.Child, f.FileId);
}
```

That will pull a file(s) by name (the user can type % into the filename textboxfor a wildcard) and then, for each file record, pull all the related child records..

The tables in the stringly typed dataset are also nicer to query via LINQ:

```
someDataset.File.Where(f => f.FileId == "hello");
```

Comment: Is there another way except DataSet and navigate, a way like DataBinding or SqlCommandBuilder to complete my previous Code in Delete case?

Comment: If you mean "is there a way to delete rows without downloading them first?" then sure - right click the relevant table adapter, add a query.. query that deletes rows.. write the query using whatever criteria you want, then you can just call it. For example you might add a query like

Comment: `DELETE FROM Person WHERE Name like @name`, call it DeleteByName and call it like `somePersonTableAdapter.DeleteByName("smith%");`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm very glad for each your reply.. i mean my above code.. Update and Insert is good but Delete No.. i search for code like:

Comment: DataTable dtNew = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
                for (int i = 0; i < dtNew.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dtNew.Rows[i][0].ToString() == dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Update");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Delete");
                    }
                }

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're aiming to do. A data row has a property (RowState) that tracks what has been done to the row. When it is downloaded the rowstate is unchanged. If you alter some property such as setting the Name to "hello", the RowState is Modified. If you remove the row, it marks as Deleted. If you make a new one and add it to the table the rowstate is added. When time comes to save the table adapter will enumerate all the changed rows, looking at their RowState; if a state is Added, the INSERT is run. If Modified, an UPdATE is run. If Deleted, a DELETE runs

Comment: DataRows also track the original values and the new values for various purposes including knowing if someone else altered the row while you had your copy (so you don't end up overwriting their changes with yours) - the code you posted in the comment looks like you're trying to replicate functionality that already exists in a robust fashion

Comment: Ok. Thank you Mr. Caius Jard for all replies.. this problem from two weeks ago, I don't understand and i will not complete this project. thank you again..

Comment: If you follow the steps in the answer you will get a program that loads child records and can save them.. so you can take some time to make it look pretty, but basically all the functionality you seek is in the answer