# Converting value from datagridview to a text box

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, selectionchanged

My code is below, I cannot for the life of me get the value from a Data table to display in a text box on my main form. I recently came to a realization that DataGridView is not the same as DataTable. Which I think got me much closer. I was originally having issues getting to the specific index as datatable doesn't work that way. Now that I'm using datagridview I feel like I'm pretty much there but missing something silly.

## My Code

```cs
    private void dt_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            dgv.DataSource = dt;

            if (dgv.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                active_Description.Text = 
                Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["Description"].Value);
                active_Cost.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["Cost"].Value);
                active_Diameter.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["Diameter"].Value);
                active_Last_Used.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["CareTaker"].Value);
                active_Location.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["Location"].Value);
                active_OAL.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["OAL"].Value);
                active_Vendor.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["Vendor"].Value);
            }

        }
```

Comment: There is an error? Or empty value? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True; a DataGridView is a UI device that *shows* data in a tabular fashion, something similar to how Excel appears. A DataTable is a device that *stores* data in a tabular fashion. If you had data to store you put it in a datatable, and if you wanted to show it you can tell a datagridview tonuse the table as a source of data but they are very distinct things

DataGridView shows many rows of data at once, whereas text boxes can only show one value. Generally when we mix the two we end up using the DGV as a navigation device (it shows eg 20 rows and we can click one of them to make it "the current row") and any text boxes also using the same data source typically show the current row data

The code you're trying to put together manually there can be much more simply done using data binding where both the DataGridView and the TextBoxes are bound to the same BindingSource; the BS takes care of maintaining notion of "the current row"

To make your life easy when doing this, follow these steps:

- add a new file to your project, of type DataSet
- open the dataset, right click the surface and add a datatable, call it Product (you look like you're making some kind of product related system)
- right click the table and add a new column, call it Description
- add another column for Cost(type decimal?) Diameter(int? Decimal?) etc
- switch to your form designer
- open the data sources window (view menu, other windows) - if you're on .net core it doesn't work at the moment, so here's hoping you're on framework. There are other ways to do this process on core, it's just more of a nuisance
- expand all the nodes in Data Sources
- you can see parent node, Product, with a little grid looking icon. It has children whose icons look more like textboxes etc
- drag product node onto the form; a DataGridView appears, along with a dataset, binding source and navigator (in the bottom tray)
- drag a few of the child nodes to the form too, textboxes appear but you'll note that they reuse the existing products binding source
- if you inspect the DGV and textboxes you'll find that they have a data source set to the binding source, and the binding source has a data source of the dataset (and data member of products table)

That's really all you need to do; you could put some code into your constructor that fills your dataset with data or you can do it at runtime. do it at runtime for now; run the app, enter 3 or so rows worth of data and then click up and down between them; you'll note that the textboxes change depending on what is the active row in the DGV

If you want to see the code that visual studio wrote to wire all this up it's in the Designer.cs file

If you're getting this data out of a database take a look at my answer to Michal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712612/how-can-i-update-database-after-changes-in-datagridview/69714352?noredirect=1#comment123270275_69714352) - actually it has relevance to what is posted above; there Michal  refs data out of a db, so a lot of the answer is geared towards pulling that data out and into a dataset, showing it in DGV and textboxes and then sending it back, but the screenshots and other relevant parts about showing and manipulating data (that is in a data set) will help you out too

Comment: will give this a shot and look at the answer to Michal. I am pulling from a Excel document. thank you for the explanation on all of this!

Comment: There are various ways of pulling data from excel; the most direct for what you're doing it perhaps to use the jet/ace db driver (Microsoft Access) to open the xlsx; a data adapter (and I'd presume a table adapter; I've never tried) can forge a connection to an excel file as if it were a database, and fill a datatable with it. Other ways will probably work out too; some library like CsvHelper that can turn a csv file into a suite of objects, can probably be made to churn out your strongly typed data rows; the Products table I mentioned above has rows with named properties you can deser to

Comment: see my excel sheet actually just references a .json file. so its kinda redundant to use the excel.. im looking into deserialization right now. answered above works ok for me.

Comment: Easiest way to do that one; take your json and paste it into QuickType.io- it will generate a bunch of classes for you. You can then double click on one of the tables in your dataset to get into the code behind and make a partial class for the data row, pull the properties from the classes QT made and paste them into your partial class for the data row, then wire up the json properties so they set the column properties. I would have advocated just configuring things so the json deser sets the column props directly but I think they're auto generated with no easy way to add attributes to them..

Comment: All in you then can make the json deserializer deser a json record straight into a data row

Comment: thanks for input. ill have to give it ago

Comment: is there a resource to do what you are saying? pretty rough explanation and im having a hard time of it.

Comment: Mmm, downside of (and why we're encouraged not to get into) using comments as an extended chat mechanism; they aren't verry good at conveying a lot of well formatted info. There isn't anything I can think of automagically to do it, but I could give some more targeted advice in another question; pose one that includes some example json data (simplistic version, maybe 2 or 3 properties, rather than a 40+ property behemoth would be ideal) and link me to it; I'll put some code together and some screenshots to explain it a bit better

Comment: Oh.. i've just thought of a simpler way round it. Post up and I'll make a demo for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756427/binding-json-data-to-a-datagridview-in-c-sharp