# Error ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized C# (Access)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, sql-insert, executenonquery

I have some code like this:

```
var queryIns = "...";

try
{
    var rowInsert = u.insert(queryIns);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    var msg = "Error";
    MessageBox.Show(msg,...);
}
```

and my command is:

```
public int Command(string queryCommand)
{
    using var conn = openConnection(); //private method that returns the connection with connection string
    using OleDbCommand cmd = getCommand(queryCommand, conn); //private method that returns the command with connection and query
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Finally these are the methods:

```
private OleDbCommand getCommand(string queryString, OleDbConnection conn)
{
    using var cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
    return cmd;
}

private OleDbConnection openConnection()
{
    using var conn= new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}
```

The problem is that all this throws an exception

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Could someone help me T_T?

Comment: The problem is that you have `using var conn` in that method and it will close the connection at the end of the method meaning it returns a closed connection.  Instead you should keep the code that creates the connection and does the query together in one method.

Comment: Simplify your life: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712612/how-can-i-update-database-after-changes-in-datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use *disposed* (closed with all resources released) connection:

```
private OleDbConnection openConnection()
{
    // you create the connection
    using var conn= new OleDbConnection(connString); 
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}                                                    // <- and here you dispose it
```

The very same problem with `Command`: the `cmd` you return is disposed.

```
private OleDbCommand getCommand(string queryString, OleDbConnection conn)
{
    using var cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn); // <- command created 
    return cmd;
}                                                        // <- and disposed
```

You can drop `using` in both methods:

```
private OleDbConnection openConnection()
{
    // we create connection
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connString); 

    try { 
      // try it to open  
      conn.Open(); 
      // return opened (and not disposed!) connection
      return conn;
    }
    catch {
      // on open failure we dispose conenction (to prevent resources leakage) 
      conn.Dispose();
      // and rethrow the exception (to know the exact problem)
      throw; 
    }
} 

// Here we just return a command
private OleDbCommand getCommand(string queryString, OleDbConnection conn) =>
  new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);
```

Or may be merge methods into one:

```
public int Command(string queryCommand) 
{
  using var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString); 
  conn.Open();

  using var cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn);

  return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // here both conn and cmd will be disposed
```

Comment: ok it worked, many thanks. So the problem was in the using in the getCommand() method, right?

Comment: @galidan: the problem was in `using` *misusing*: `using` disposed both connection and comamnd. It is `Command` method that should `Dispose` connection and command

Answer (score 0):

Using will close everything you use with using, connection, command, httprequest, etc.

```
 using (var conn= new OleDbConnection(connString)) {
       using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn)) {
              conn.Open();
               return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } //private method that returns the command with connection and query
  }; //private method that returns the connection with connection string
```